# Classification of all subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain whose underlying additive group is finitely generated free and whose field of fractions $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there a method of classifiying *all* subrings of $R$? Is there perhaps a variant of Galois theory? (Notice that I don't want to restrict to étale subrings!)

For example, the subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ should be $\mathbb{Z}[z \cdot \sqrt{2}]$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, right? Here we also see that the subring structure is more complicated than the subgroup structure of the automorphism group.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable place to start: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0195922

That said, this seems like a pretty hopelessly difficult problem. Even if you wanted something simpler like "classify all orders in $\mathcal{O}_K$" then you'd geometrically be asking for "list all singular curves with normalization $X$" (for some given non-singular curve $X$). This seems very hard. 

So, it seems like a first beginning question one might ask is "what are the affine curves $X$ which are birational to $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$?"

Comment: Just to comment, the only tenable case I can imagine to this (although, this might just be a lack of knowledge on my part) is to classify, in the geometric case, *plane curves* with the desired normalization. One could just take your plane curve $X$ and modify any set of points with a singularity, the set of which is well-understood for plane curves (e.g. $n$-nodes, etc.).